# How to delete cookies using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I have cookies with commas, Now i want to remove when particular item was clicked, How to remove from that list 
I have cookies like this,

```
879273565,879269461,879273569,659234741

artistcontrollers.controller("CartController", ["$scope", "$http", "$cookies", "$cookieStore", function ($scope, $http, $cookies, $cookieStore){

var list = $cookies.get('basketlist');

console.log("Before removed "+list);

$scope.DeleteCookie = function (id){
    console.log(id);
    $cookies.remove(id);
    console.log("After removed "+list);
}

}]);
```

Html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart_class btn btn-default" ng-click="DeleteCookie(cartlist.trackId)">Remove</a>
```

How to remove one by one when i clicked on particular item id

Answer (score 0):

you cant delete particular value unless you will parse it.

```
artistcontrollers.controller("CartController", ["$scope", "$http", "$cookies", "$cookieStore", function ($scope, $http, $cookies, $cookieStore){

var list = $cookies.get('basketlist');

$scope.DeleteCookie = function (id){
    var cookiesArray = list.split(',');
    var id  = cookiesArray.indexof(id);
    if(id !== -1)
    {
      cookiesArray.splice(id,1);
    }
    $cookies.put('basketList', cookiesArray.join())
}

}]);
```